# Did the entire generation of the wilderness lose their Olam Haba

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, maseches-sanhedrin, agada-stories-legends

What does the Gemara mean when it says (Sanhedrin 108),

> The generation of the wilderness have no share in the future world and will not stand at the [last] judgement, as it is written in this wilderness they shall be consumed, and there they shall die.

Does this apply to the entire generation? What about the Zikeinim? What about everyone else, surely there were very holy & righteous people among them?

Comment: Remember that your quotation is not necessarily the opinion of the Gemara, but of Rabbi Akiva. Rabbi Eliezer disagrees with the statement, and says the opposite, that they _do_ have a share in Olam Haba, because of _Ifsu Li Chasidai..._ (Tehillim 50:5).

Comment: Is this decree specific to those who died in the desert, i.e. the ones who were age 20+ at the time of the decree? If so, it makes sense. Apparently lashon hara about the land of Israel was a serious sin.